# Zabbix new Trapper item not accepting data for about 10 min

Tags: zabbix

After creating a new trapper item on Zabbix server web page (PHP), it fails to send data via `zabbix_sender` tool like:

```
zabbix_sender -vv -z zabbix.server.host -p 10051 -s "test.node.001" -k "trap.item.001" -o "0.0"
zabbix_sender [24284]: DEBUG: answer [{"response":"success","info":"processed: 0; failed: 1; total: 1; seconds spent: 0.000031"}]
info from server: "processed: 0; failed: 1; total: 1; seconds spent: 0.000031"
```

But the same `zabbix_sender` command success after about 10 minutes.

I cannot find any reference about this problem. Is this some kind of cache in zabbix server?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `zabbix_server` syncs configuration from the database every `CacheUpdateFrequency` seconds. By default, this setting is 60 seconds, but it may have been changed for your installation.

Comment: To add to the answer, see https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/appendix/config/zabbix_server for more detail on the server config and https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/appendix/config/zabbix_proxy for the proxy (where parameter `ConfigFrequency` affects things). Also note that in most cases you shouldn't set these parameters to low values.

Comment: Thanks, it works after changing `CacheUpdateFrequency`.